# How to use HAVE_BOOST in ax_boost_base

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, configure

The [ax_boost_base page](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_base.html) indicates that it sets HAVE_BOOST. So I tried it in my configure.ac file:

```
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.48],, [AC_MSG_ERROR([libfoo needs Boost, but it was not found in your system])])
AC_MSG_NOTICE(["HAVE_BOOST value"])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([$HAVE_BOOST])
```

When I run `configure`, HAVE_BOOST does not seem to have any value:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.48 (104800)... yes
configure: "HAVE_BOOST value"
configure:
```

How do I use this HAVE_BOOST in my configure.ac? Specifically, I want to append a file into my AC_OUTPUT if HAVE_BOOST is set. For example, if HAVE_BOOST is not set, then I want:

```
AC_OUTPUT([
Makefile 
include/Makefile
comm/Makefile
ordinary_app/Makefile
])
```

But if HAVE_BOOST is set, then I want this:

```
AC_OUTPUT([
Makefile 
include/Makefile
comm/Makefile
ordinary_app/Makefile
boost_enabled_app/Makefile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to set the result back to some variable. You can try this

```
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.48],
[have_boost=yes],
[AC_MSG_ERROR([libfoo needs Boost, but it was not found in your system])]
)
AC_MSG_NOTICE(["have_boost value"])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([$have_boost])
```

The HAVE_BOOST is set in the m4 macro `ax_boost_base` uses `AC_DEFINE` that would be generated in config.h. It's not a shell variable.
Eventually you can use the var $have_boost to get what you want

```
if test "$have_boost" != yes; then
    AC_OUTPUT([
    Makefile 
    include/Makefile
    comm/Makefile
    ordinary_app/Makefile
    ])
else
    AC_OUTPUT([
    Makefile 
    include/Makefile
    comm/Makefile
    ordinary_app/Makefile
    boost_enabled_app/Makefile
    ])
fi
```